# Java RandomAccessFile how to Read nth byte as a character

Tags: java, seek, randomaccessfile

I was learning java fileoperations, and I was trying to read nth byte as character in a text file. I used RandomAccessFile (I am not sure if this is the right module to use here), and my code is

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
public class testclass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("temptext.txt", "r");
    f.seek(200);
    System.out.println(f.readChar());
    }
}
```

This is printing some unknown characters, which is not mentioned in the text file. What am I doing wrong here? My final aim is to reverse the entire text in the text file using a forloop, if I can get this right.

Comment: Bytes and chars don't always align (for utf-8 for instance). What charset do you have in textfile?

Comment: @Jan it is the default ascii text in linux with linux style line terminators. It was created with a vi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readChar()):

> public final char readChar() throws IOException
>
> Reads a character from this file. This method **reads two bytes** from the file, >starting at the current file pointer. If the bytes read, in order, are b1 >and b2, where 0 <= b1, b2 <= 255, then the result is equal to:
>       (char)((b1 << 8) | b2)

So for your example to work, you shoud use `readByte()` instead.

Comment: Thank you Jan. After this, I could see that the returned value is the ASCII value of the character.